# Chart creation in php and my sql using google visualization

Tags: php

Hi am trying to create chart with the following query.

```
    $sql_no=mysql_query("SELECT MONTH(calldate) AS month,COUNT(*) AS nosuccess FROM     details WHERE result =1 GROUP BY MONTH(cdate)");
   $call=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_no);?>
    <?php
   While($call=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_no)){
      $success[]=$call['nosuccess'];
      $monname[]=date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0,$call['month']) );   
      }
```

and here is my chart code:

```
    var total = <?php echo json_encode($total) ?>;
var s=<?php echo json_encode($success) ?>;
var m=<?php echo json_encode($monname) ?>;
var d=3;

     var result=[];
     for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
      result.push([m[i],s[i]]);
     }     
    alert(result.length);

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Success');
   // data.addColumn('number', 'Failure');
  /*data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', 1170, 460],
      ['2006',  860, 580],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);*/

 data.addRows(result);

    var options = {
      width: 800, height: 340,
      title: 'Call details'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

chart is not displaying . when am hide the data.addrows(result); chart displays with no lines..did you find any errors help needed immediatly...

Answer (score 0):

In you PHP, is there a `<div id="chart_div"></div>`

Also `json_encode` does not create an array for you.

```
var s=<?php echo json_encode($success) ?>; !== var s = [xxx];
```

You need `var s = [<?=$success?>];`

Comment: hi i have tried what you said but it still not working.. i have tested json_encode it returns array and it's working fine..any suggesstions..i have a div u mentioned in my php

Comment: You have try the code google provided in their API doc, and made sure the chart showed up before making the changes to suite your need. If that is the case. I think it has everything to do with how you are populating the results. have you look at the alert(result.toString()) ? just to see what you are pushing into the data block.